# PHP - Array getting empty outside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, opencart

Hi I have a below code in opencart (responsible to display payment options in checkout step - 4),

```
$method_data = array();

    $results = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('payment');

                  foreach ($results as $result) {
                        if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                            $this->load->model('payment/' . $result['code']);

                            $method = $this->{'model_payment_' . $result['code']}->getMethod($payment_address, $total);

                            if ($method) {
                                $method_data[$result['code']] = $method;
                            }
                        }       
                       print_r($method_data); // Getting dump of data's
                    }   


             print_r($method_data); // Empty Array
```

I've checked all possible combinations for this issue like,

- No other variable with same name ($method_data),
- Foreach loop executing 4 times (have 4 available payment options).

Did anyone have any idea on what's happening behind this issue.

Comment: What do you maan be getting dump of data?? does in foreach `$method_data` have desirable output??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check once again with the following code :

```
 if ($method) {
                   $method_data[][$result['code']] = $method;
              }
```

It will make the array two dimensional. 
Please check and let me know if you need any help further.

**NOTE : Seems the code in CI.**